# VPS server is slow

Tags: webserver, vps, linode, web-performance

I have a VPS server with Linode. At first it was very fast but now it takes upto 23 seconds to load a webpage. This is so appalling. I have tried configuring Apache and MySQL key buffer but all to no avail. Can I get a standard VPS configuration. 
My VPS is a Linode 16GB Ram with 320GB SSD. According to google analytics, I get to 2,073,000 page views per month. What proper configuration do the server need to be fast? And how can I increase server response time (currently, google pagespeed says the server response time is 1.2 seconds and this is very slow.) this has been a great challenge to me.

Comment: I don’t think this is a suitable question at SO since it’s not about programming or tools used for it. It might work on Server Fault but you’ll have to read their rules and help pages. In any case it’ll need a lot more information and you’ll need to do basic benchmarking and detective work before anyone can say anything since nobody else knows what your server is doing. Load averages, what processes are using CPU, IO etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe mainserver is overloaded by other vms i would test the Server with some tools, like test the Speed of copy data.

btw for 80$ i would buy me a real server

Intel® Xeon® Gold 6140
64 GB DDR4 RAM (ECC)
14 dedizierte Kerne
240 GB SSD / 2,0 TB SAS
52$ Netcup for example

if u like stay on the server would be good to know which software ur using, sometimes the mistake is somewehre else, like my page had a loadtime of 16 seconds(i forgot 2 index keys in the db to set)

Comment: I use LEMP stack